# Остановить CSS анимацию

Tags: css, анимация

Помогите решить вопрос, или подскажите как остановить css анимацию. Есть такой вот прелоадер, нужно оставить анимацию когда виден весь круг точек и запустить по событию(например добавление класса в контейнер).

```css
.holder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #2D2F48;
}

.preloader {
  /* size */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  animation: rotatePreloader 2s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes rotatePreloader {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateZ(-360deg);
  }
}
.preloader div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.preloader div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.preloader div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  animation: rotateCircle1 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 9;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(36deg);
  }
  7% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  57% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateZ(36deg);
  animation: rotateCircle2 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 8;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle2 {
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5.0001% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  12% {
    transform: rotateZ(-36deg);
  }
  62% {
    transform: rotateZ(-36deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateZ(72deg);
  animation: rotateCircle3 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 7;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle3 {
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10.0002% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(-36deg);
  }
  17% {
    transform: rotateZ(-72deg);
  }
  67% {
    transform: rotateZ(-72deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateZ(108deg);
  animation: rotateCircle4 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 6;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle4 {
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15.0003% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(-72deg);
  }
  22% {
    transform: rotateZ(-108deg);
  }
  72% {
    transform: rotateZ(-108deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateZ(144deg);
  animation: rotateCircle5 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 5;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle5 {
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20.0004% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(-108deg);
  }
  27% {
    transform: rotateZ(-144deg);
  }
  77% {
    transform: rotateZ(-144deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
  animation: rotateCircle6 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 4;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle6 {
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25.0005% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(-144deg);
  }
  32% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  }
  82% {
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateZ(216deg);
  animation: rotateCircle7 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 3;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle7 {
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30.0006% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotateZ(-216deg);
  }
  87% {
    transform: rotateZ(-216deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateZ(252deg);
  animation: rotateCircle8 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle8 {
  35% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35.0007% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(-216deg);
  }
  42% {
    transform: rotateZ(-252deg);
  }
  92% {
    transform: rotateZ(-252deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateZ(288deg);
  animation: rotateCircle9 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle9 {
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40.0008% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(-252deg);
  }
  47% {
    transform: rotateZ(-288deg);
  }
  97% {
    transform: rotateZ(-288deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preloader div:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateZ(324deg);
  animation: rotateCircle10 2s infinite linear;
  z-index: 0;
}

@keyframes rotateCircle10 {
  45% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  45.0009% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateZ(-288deg);
  }
  52% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
  }
  102% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-324deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="preloader"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Честно, старался, но ничего путного не нашел. Возможно ли это?

Comment: вы добавьте класс `.play`, и все анимации сложите в `.play div:nth-child`,  а остальное оставьте в `preloader`. подкорректируйте начальные позиции, и будет что хотите.

Comment: Спасибо! Решил уже похоже, добавил класс в контейнер, вернул видимость точкам постоянно с таким классом в контейнере и остановил анимацию. Получил то что хотел.